# Off-site Cardholder Data Storage

Tags: storage, pci-compliance

Is there a service or site out there that will store cardholder data for me?  I don't need any kind of transaction processing or recurring billing... I just need somewhere that I can store data on until someone in my company is able to look at it.

The specific need is allowing customers to input data that will be used for credit checks. Name, Address, Credit Card(s), and the such.

Google Checkout, PayPal, NetSuite, and Authorize.net seem to be what everyone suggests to me, but they don't offer what I need -- they're just payment gateways.

Answer (score 1):

In general there won't be many companies that store that data for you and they will be processors.  The reason is because of PCI compliance. You have to follow strict standards to store card numbers.  Check out the Wikipedia article on PCI compliance, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard.

The PCI compliance website might also give you some leads if you are still interested. https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/